# Multiple AJAX requests in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that pulls data from two locations and places the returned content on a modal dialog that is displayed to the user.

Both requests are asynchronous because they're cross-domain. The problem lies in that I don't want to display the modal until both requests have finished loading. How can I check to make sure both requests have finished before loading the modal?

I have tried placing the openModal functions in the success handler of the second request and that works when the first requests finishes loading before the second request, but sometimes this isn't the case.

Here's a copy of my code:

```
function loadData(id) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://someurl.com/v1.0/controller1/' + id,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        // Do some stuff to the data
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://someurl.com/v1.0/controller2/' + id,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        // Do some stuff to the data

        openModal();
    }
});
}

function openModal() {
// Open the modal
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the new version of jQuery -- 1.5. It has support for exactly your problem, you can check out this blog post for the solution of your problem: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You could put the one of the ajax requests inside the success callback of the other request, but that wouldn't be as efficient as having them both request at the same time. Then you'd just have to put the openModal call inside the success callback of the inner ajax request. Not optimal, it would be a quick and easy fix if this solution would work for you until a better option is found.

I'm going to keep thinking on this one...

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.when(
   $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?", {
        tags: "moon",
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
   }),
   $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?", {
        tags: "bird",
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
   })).then(function (res1, res2) {

  });
```