# How to run a PHP script and display results only when a row is shown with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, soap

I am really unsure of how to code this properly, so I would like it if someone could point me on the right track.

I will have a SOAP+XML array which will have values matched up to a MYSQL table of jobs. The jobs then display in a  with a hidden row. In each hidden row, I will have 3 separate SOAP+XML requests which will display 3 other bits of info. The user can then click on the job and with javascript, it displays the hidden row below and therefor, the extra information.

My interface right now
1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e50c.png
2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/jofoP.png

The problem is when I scale this up, if the user chooses to display 100 jobs on the page. I need to hit the server for the first SOAP+XML request to get the jobs, then for each job, hit it 3 more times. So if I'm displaying 100 jobs, I'm hitting the SOAP server 301 times.

What I need is a way for it to only hit the server for the 1 initial SOAP+XML request, and then when someone initiates the javascript to view the hidden row, it starts the 3 soap requests for extra job info. That way the user isn't waiting for information they don't want to see and it doesn't bog down my server. The problem is I really don't know how to do this.

I really don't know much javascript, but I do know a good deal more PHP. Here's the script I'm using to hide the secondary rows in the table: http://pastebin.com/jhvaW0X4

Can anyone chime in on how I should go about getting this done?

Thank you!

Comment: This somewhat confusing... is all the data in your back end or do you have some data stored in your database and some pulled from a 3rd party using soap?

Comment: @MichaelHarroun The initial SOAP+XML request gets the entire list of jobs in an array. So that's where the data is coming from. But for each, I am matching up the job number field to a separate MYSQL table (for user prefs, if they want to hide a job, etc) but that is irrelevant.

Comment: We need more information. Are you familiar with ajax? First, it should be easy to combine your 3 requests into one if the data is all in your database. You can use ajax to fetch the details for just one job on demand and insert it as a new <tr> into the <table>.

Comment: @cryocide the 3 SOAP requests must stay as 3 separate requests. Its an outside API I'm working with. The data is coming from SOAP, not from my database (it is being matched up if the job number exists in a jobs database, but this will function at 100% if that table is empty).

Comment: Ok, that was just a suggestion for performance. Your problem should be easy to solve with ajax. I'd start with a basic tutorial (http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp, for example) and then post any specific questions you have about implementation.

Comment: @cryocide: please, do not cite w3schools, they are not a trusted source, check [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com)

Comment: you can hit the soap 1 time an get all the info

Comment: @TomSarduy the way it works is theres 1 request for getting a list of job numbers and descriptions (getjobs) and then theres one for getting tracking info for a particular job (gettrackingbyjobid) and then there's one for plant location (getplantlocationbyjobid) etc... Its not 1 SOAP service that I'm hitting up for all this. That's why there has to be multiple requests...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem, but you can make an ajax request on a javascript event, in this case, when the user click the job tr, make the ajax requests for the needed info, for that you can use the [$.ajax jquery method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$("table#report1.report > tbody > tr.odd").click(function()
{
    if(!$(this).next("tr").hasClass('shown'))
    {
        //Put here your ajax request

        $.ajax({
            url: yourSoapURL, getting tracking info url
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapMessage,
            processData: false,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
            success: function(soapMessage) {
                    //Add the tracking info to the tr that will be show
                    $(this).next("tr").text(soapMessage);
                    //Now the text is in the tr, show it!
                    $(this).next("tr").show();
                    $(this).next("tr").addClass("shown");
            },
            error: OnError
        });


    }
    else
    {
        $(this).next("tr").hide();          
        $(this).next("tr").removeClass("shown");
    }
```

That's the idea. If you want to manage multiple AJAX requests then read this: [Multiple AJAX requests in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959505/multiple-ajax-requests-in-jquery).